# Reduce 2 foreach loops into a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, loops

Is there any way to reduce the following code into Linq form?

```
foreach (var current in currentWhiteListApps)
{
    var exists = false;

    foreach (var whiteList in clientSideWhiteLists)
    {
       if (current.appID.Equals(whiteList.appID))
       {
           exists = true;
       }
    }
    if (!exists)
    {
        deleteList.Add(current);
    }
}
```

All I can think of is:

```
currentWhiteListApps.Select(x => {
    var any = clientSideWhiteLists.Where(y => y.appID.Equals(x.appID));
    if (any.Any())
        deleteList.AddRange(any.ToArray());
    return x;
});
```

**Reason For LINQ**
`LINQ` is far more readable than nested foreach loops, and requires less code. So this is the reason I would like it in `LINQ`

Comment: Any particular reason why you want this in `LINQ`? It probably will not optimize the code and will also reduce readability.

Comment: "LINQ rule #1": Unless you are able to come with LINQ query yourself in 3 minutes, it is not worth using it. :)

Comment: Edit to LINQ rule #1, If your pro.... I'm not in any way shape or form an expert in Linq, so that rule just doesn't apply.

Comment: I think, in most cases `LINQ` actually increases readability, looking at Danial Hilgarth's answer, its far more readable then my original code. It's easier to follow with `LINQ` english terms like `Where`, `All`. when read allowed, it makes farrrr more sense, so I completely disagree with your comment there.

Comment: @No1_Melman: I agree with JleruOHeP in that you shouldn't overuse LINQ. Nowadays a lot of people want to use LINQ although LINQ wouldn't actually provide any benefit. As always: Use the right tool for the job. Sometimes that's LINQ, sometimes that's ordinary loops.

Comment: When dealing with databases, `LINQ` is essential. However, since enumerating and looping are very similar if not identical, it comes down to pure choice in the matter. It doesn't have a performance impact either way, and just because more people are used to reading `foreach()` rather than `.Where()` doesn't mean that you can't use `LINQ` all the time. I see no problem with using it or over using it, its a new software technology - make use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var deleteList = currentWhiteListApps.Where(x =>
                     clientSideWhiteLists.All(y => !x.appID.Equals(y.appID)))
                                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like a decent answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var deleteList = currentWhiteListApps.Except(clientSideWhiteLists).ToList();
```

This solution assumes that both collections contains elements of the same type and this type has overriden Equals() that compares appID.

Comment: +1: if the assumption is valid, then `Except` is the method to use. Otherwise, implement an equality comparer and pass it to `Except`.

Comment: That seems perfect. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this out on LINQPad and it doesn't yield the results that the other answer and my original code yields. And my code yields the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var validIds = new HashSet<int>(clientSideWhiteLists.Select(x => x.appId));
var deleteList = currentWhiteListApps.Where(x => !validIds.Contains(x.appId)).ToList();
```

Comment: That is a very interesting way to do it. I did think about using HashSet. Nice :)